# Parse HTML tags from a string from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a blog and I want to make the text appear a lot better.. I use MySQL and PHP for my script, the script is pulling out from the database a $text with the article's body and I wanted to add some tags in the MySQL record but it seems they doesn't appear on the website. I'd like to know if there's anything I can do to parse those html tags from a MySQL string

Here is some code:

```
$p = $posts->getPost($_GET['id']);
$u = $users->getUser($p['autor']);
echo "<div class='row-fluid'><div class='span9'>
<div class='bara'></div><div class='barabody'>
<h1>" . $p['titlu'] . "</h1>
" . $p['text'] . "
<div style='float: right;'><i class='icon-time'></i> Data: " . date("d M Y",$p['data']) . "</div>
</div>
</div>";
```

Comment: You look to be doing it right. How does the output look?

Comment: It looks the same even if I insert html tags or not..

Comment: try looking into source code of generated page

Comment: There aren't any tags that I added in the MySQL record.

Comment: @dei.andrei98: Can you please copy paste the HTML source of the corresponding section?

Comment: I resolved it, I have a truncate function which included a strip_tag , now I removed it and it's working, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML data coming from Database is being converted into HTML entities at some point. Either find the point where it is being converted by using

[**`htmlspecialchars()`**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

**or** 
you better decode the data when it comes from the database by

[**`htmlspecialchars_decode()`**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: It doesn't show the tags in the text and it doesn't apply them to the text.. I want them to be applied to the text, but this function didn't change anything.